# Not able to install indicator-cpufreq

Tags: package-management, locate

I am trying to install indicator-cpufreq on 21.04 ubuntu, but not able to due to Unable to locate package error.

```
[sudo] password for boguehaze: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package indicator-cpufreq
```

Any ideas why?

I had the same issue trying to install Filezilla, but I managed to install it from source.
Here is my list of repository.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sloY6.png)

Answer (score 1):

Managed to sort it out by changing *Download from: Main server* in *Additional Drivers*

[image]